# Side Products of Dow's process

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, synthesis

In [Dow's process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dow_process) of manufacture of phenol, $\ce{PhCl}$ is fused with $\ce{NaOH}$ at high temperature and pressure. What are the possible side products? And what is the intermediate formed?

I think the intermediate will be benzyne. After the formation of benzyne, $\ce{OH-}$ nucleophilic attack takes place. the reaction mixture also contains some phenoxide ions. So Diphenyl ether is a possible side product (Formed by nucleophilic attack of $\ce{PhO-}$). But the answer given species two side products: Diphenyl ether and p-phenyl phenol. How can I explain the second product?

Comment: $\ce{C6H5ONa}$ might again react with left over $\ce{C6H5Cl + NaOH}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before we can consider the reaction, we must consider the conversion of the reactants into the reacting species:

[image]
[image]

Now, we may consider the reaction occurring between these two species:

[image]
[image]

The product of this reaction is now easily converted into para-phenyl phenol by an acid workup.

Comment: The benzyne should be write between square brakets because it is not an isolated compound.

Comment: @Shadock It's intermediate not transition state; otherwise you'd be right.

Comment: @Mithoron Non-isolated intermediates are typically written in brackets. Transition states are written in brackets and include the double-dagger notation.

Comment: I actually made a lot of technical mistakes. I hope this fixes them. My ChemDraw file got corrupted, so I had to do it all over again from scratch...